# How to use go-retryablehttp with a Client with a custom Transport?

Tags: go

I would like to understand how to use [go-retryablehttp](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp) with a Client with a custom Transport, let's say for instance to disable TLS validation, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the underlying http client as seen in [this issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp/issues/51). Here is a small example of ignoring an self signed cert error at 127.0.0.1:8030

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"

    "github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }
    retryClient := retryablehttp.NewClient()
    retryClient.HTTPClient.Transport = tr

    req, err := retryablehttp.NewRequest("GET", "https://127.0.0.1:8030", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = retryClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```